# oracle sql cast a collection to another data type in sql statement

Tags: sql, casting, oracle12c, collect

I have a collection of datasets that I need to convert into a string

```
 SELECT COLLECT (col1) FROM test_table;
```

does anyone know how to cast/convert the collection into a string in an sql statement?

The DB I am using is 12c

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.